# Bind configuration?

Tags: dns, bind, dig

When I execute dig static.acer.com I have a different answer than if I use google's DNS.

With my dns server : 
    # dig static.acer.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3 <<>> static.acer.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 14150
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;static.acer.com.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
static.acer.com.        86400   IN      CNAME   static-akamai.gtm.acer.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gtm.acer.com.           60      IN      SOA     gtm1.acer.com. hostmaster.gtm1.acer.com. 576 10800 3600 604800 60

;; Query time: 986 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 01 12:58:01 WEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128`
```

With google's DNS:

```
# dig @8.8.8.8 static.acer.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 static.acer.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6974
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;static.acer.com.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
static.acer.com.        12555   IN      CNAME   static-akamai.gtm.acer.com.
static-akamai.gtm.acer.com. 29  IN      CNAME   static.acer.com.edgesuite.net.
static.acer.com.edgesuite.net. 20826 IN CNAME   a1449.b.akamai.net.
a1449.b.akamai.net.     19      IN      A       77.67.41.131
a1449.b.akamai.net.     19      IN      A       77.67.41.163

;; Query time: 73 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 01 13:00:10 WEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 180
```

What do I shall change in named.conf to alter my dns answer?

Using host command :

```
# host static.acer.com
Host static.acer.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
# vi /etc/resolv.conf
# host static.acer.com
static.acer.com is an alias for static-akamai.gtm.acer.com.
static-akamai.gtm.acer.com is an alias for static.acer.com.edgesuite.net.
static.acer.com.edgesuite.net is an alias for a1449.b.akamai.net.
a1449.b.akamai.net has address 77.67.41.163
a1449.b.akamai.net has address 77.67.41.131
```

If I made a dig with +trace, I got correct answer :

```
# dig +trace static.acer.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3 <<>> +trace static.acer.com
;; global options: +cmd
.                       516702  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       516702  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       516704  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20151011050000 20151001040000 62530 . ltB/6YE1kCZYnxKuhdz2MqjgZ0KeoehAknqroBe+VKG5rA3Ava1cRJC9 Egb7EZdSTYfCQk7T9BqyzmYoAW/+/g+53BUTWDk03qwKEr/vc7001AJ3 e4HqR5IJJjwr63pfMEPjFfAGjJ3l9IBqrrc1QTdzt8jcscI6UGPm95tg uxU=
;; Received 913 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 0 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.                    86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20151011050000 20151001040000 62530 . f8yt3kd0k6X+rWm/sEubZBXA5h0uKt4O84gzTxuSLhERczpUnc2cfcrO dKcgz7M8yRn3zPnCxOJfym4Suflyxe0afYno3bIHwhlo70hZfOHLufnJ oTpTSHpB23vsaYVa9C6kX7CFR40ZuPpoiogRHlaGCsJhXsckKjLTSQHY wRw=
;; Received 739 bytes from 199.7.91.13#53(d.root-servers.net) in 110 ms

acer.com.               172800  IN      NS      ns1.acer.com.
acer.com.               172800  IN      NS      ns2.acer.com.
acer.com.               172800  IN      NS      ns3.acer.com.
acer.com.               172800  IN      NS      ns4.acer.com.
acer.com.               172800  IN      NS      ns5.acer.com.
acer.com.               172800  IN      NS      ns6.acer.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20151007045440 20150930034440 35864 com. ZF9Dc/F3VseesL11dCPgsinARtH5gXB9FUnc1Pl6jvnQYCFWMZ4MFuMr fXQ6Zn3ULpohJNAznbn+RykzFrEiLrUaLR7hmyZ4Cao4QSCldyPlo96C lbsuLVSsOUYe/ND4YAExZUcMLsefGXERcC1cvCrv4CVG2h0giRV6lV0U evM=
T2AQSNVH0N0GGDLJ8T58H3IIBS6GN560.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - T2AT2UVLREGTIF0ST27SEF2O8RDUEIDV NS DS RRSIG
T2AQSNVH0N0GGDLJ8T58H3IIBS6GN560.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20151007045228 20150930034228 35864 com. a8wwGIyv3CrgzeOJxgBfl+fx4d91verSeNC8Oiv7X9HUXp+Sizn4A7jo 4b4Nw17YPC02/YVYV3hwOpc6Z2pCBF9Bq6sVhvFI/YK2OkkMMgs1ozx9 Zg2uqolvvsVwjKN1QIx38NMi4Xs65lH1RrymH+XpyeM8UDJoOxuN8Uqp ntQ=
;; Received 733 bytes from 192.35.51.30#53(f.gtld-servers.net) in 140 ms

static.acer.com.        86400   IN      CNAME   static-akamai.gtm.acer.com.
gtm.acer.com.           300     IN      NS      gtm1.acer.com.
gtm.acer.com.           300     IN      NS      gtm3.acer.com.
gtm.acer.com.           300     IN      NS      gtm2.acer.com.
;; Received 197 bytes from 63.66.78.35#53(ns6.acer.com) in 137 ms
```

Any clue?

**UPDATE**
After a rndc flush, I captured some packages with tcpdump :

```
14:47:55.017422 IP 10.17.2.50.49145 > ns1.acer.com.domain: 63026 [1au] A? static.acer.com. (56)
14:47:55.067398 IP ns1.acer.com.domain > 10.17.2.50.49145: 63026*- 1/3/5 CNAME static-akamai.gtm.acer.com. (197)
14:47:55.067675 IP 10.17.2.50.39069 > ns4.acer.com.domain: 8745 [1au] A? static-akamai.gtm.acer.com. (67)
14:47:55.396300 IP ns4.acer.com.domain > 10.17.2.50.39069: 8745- 0/3/5 (176)
14:47:55.396700 IP 10.17.2.50.46316 > 210.241.130.24.domain: 22322 [1au] A? static-akamai.gtm.acer.com. (67)
14:47:55.712989 IP 210.241.130.24.domain > 10.17.2.50.46316: 22322 NXDomain*- 0/1/1 (107)
```

Someone understand what is happen here? If I use a public DNS, everything works fine.

Regards,
Rui

Comment: I'm very confused as to how you managed to get both a CNAME answer _and_ an NXDOMAIN error in the same query.

Comment: I assume you are performing DNS forwarding in your named.conf.options? What server is your DNS server forwarding to? if you point dig at it, is the output the same as 8.8.8.8's?

Comment: No forward, we are a small ISP. If I use host command, it is less difficult to observe what @grawity said, with my dns server I got NXDOMAIN, with google's DNS I got  the correct answer.

Comment: Can you post a copy for your `named.conf` file and what you have set in `/etc/resolv.conf` on the box your testing from. I get 'normal' answers - Acer is actually served via akamai so any number of addresses may be returned.